# What device state can the store parameter (1010) in the canopen object dictionary be wrriten to

Tags: c, real-time, ethernet, canopen, ethercat

I am trying to figure out, what state I can store the current configuration by writing to the store index `1010.01` in the CANopen object dictionary.
I tried doing it in the preoperational state but got this error

```
Time:    2914.034 SDO slave:1 index:1010.01 error:08000022 Data cannot be transferred or stored to the application because of the present device state
```

```
uint32_t store_password =  0x65766173;
ret = ec_SDOwrite(slave, 0x1010, 0x01, FALSE, sizeof(store_password), &store_password, EC_TIMEOUTTXM);
```

It is worth noting that I am using CANopen over EtherCAT with the SOEM library.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually are in pre-operational state though? Do you have Heartbeat etc enabled so that you can verify this?

Comment: Yes, i am sure, i am able to write to other object

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like non-compliant behavior. As far as I know, CANopen does not specify which state you must be in when writing to 1010h.

I would recommend to always do this in the pre-operational state, since writing to flash etc might be time consuming and interrupt real-time behavior, if executed from the operational state (and SDO timeouts might occur).

---

Non-related to the question, it would be more readable to use this:

```
const char store_password [4] = "save"; // null termination purposely ignored
... sizeof(store_password), store_password, ...
```

This also removes the endianess dependency in your current code.